# R How to make a word cloud from a tally?

Tags: r, word-cloud

Here is the repex of a tally I have:

```
word_tally <- data.frame(scarred  = c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), 
                         happy    = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                         cheerful = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                         mad      = c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0),
                         curious  = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1))
```

To make a word cloud seems I need 1 column with all the words. How could I transform the above dataframe to make that type of structure for a word cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rep` and `colSums`:

```
words <- rep(names(word_tally), colSums(word_tally))
words
 [1] "scarred"  "scarred"  "happy"    "cheerful" "mad"     
 [6] "mad"      "mad"      "mad"      "mad"      "curious" 
[11] "curious"  "curious"  "curious"
```

Or since the frequencies are the column sums, using just the data.

```
wordcloud(names(word_tally), freq=colSums(word_tally), min.freq = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could get the data in long format and remove rows where `value = 0`.

```
library(dplyr)

tidyr::pivot_longer(word_tally, cols = everything(), names_to = "word") %>%
  filter(value != 0) %>%
  select(word)  


# A tibble: 13 x 1
#   word    
#   <chr>   
# 1 scarred 
# 2 scarred 
# 3 happy   
# 4 cheerful
# 5 mad     
# 6 mad     
# 7 mad     
# 8 mad     
# 9 mad     
#10 curious 
#11 curious 
#12 curious 
#13 curious
```

This would give all the words in one column which can be used as input for wordcloud.

---

In base R, another way could be :

```
names(word_tally)[which(word_tally != 0, arr.ind = TRUE)[,2]]
```